# File conversion from *.urdf to *.xacro

Tags: urdf, xacro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How we can convert a hand-written URDF file to a .xacro file (xml macro for generating URDF files) for robot and world models?

GDSP

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10242/file-conversion-from-*.urdf-to-*.xacro./) by [PGAM](https://answers.ros.org/users/519/pgam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 61 on 2011-06-13

Post score: 6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is no official or programmatic way of doing this, as the process is strongly dependent on the platform that you are using.

When converting from a URDF to a xacro file, I did the following:

- Create properties for commonly-used constants
- Mathematics constants: M_PI, M_2PI
- Conversion constants: Radians to Degrees, inches to centimeters
- Physics constants: Speed of Light, gravity (if needed)
- Create properties for variable components of your robot (Parts that will be constant over a run, but may change between runs)
- Wheel Radius
- Ground Clearance
- Camera Height/Angle
- Create macros for arrays of parts on your robot (a good example would be the super-structure of the turtlebot).
- Create macros for any components that are "mirrored"

  - arms
  - wheels

This would be a good starting point for creating a xacro file, in general.

Edit:

See [this tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/urdf/Tutorials/Using%20Xacro%20to%20Clean%20Up%20a%20URDF%20File) for further details and syntax.

---

Originally posted by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) with karma: 6414 on 2011-06-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 9

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Michael's answer covers the strategy well. See [this tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/urdf/Tutorials/Using%20Xacro%20to%20Clean%20Up%20a%20URDF%20File) for further details and syntax.

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2011-06-13

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) on 2011-06-13**:
Good catch, I forgot that there was an entire tutorial on that.